# Efficient/ straight forward way to get integer array from stdin in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

My approach

- get array elements as string with delimiter such as space or comma
- split the string
- Convert each element into number and push into the array

The code looks like this:

```
puts 'Enter array elements with a space'
array_as_string = gets 
if array_as_string.length > 0
  input_array = []
  array_as_string.split(' ').each { |x| input_array.push(x.to_i) }
else
  puts 'Invalid input'
end
```

Is there a better/ efficient alternative or a straight forward way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default argument for `split` is whitespace.
The idiom to do
something with every element in an array and get an array as result
is `map`.

```
puts "Enter array elements with a space"
array_as_string = gets
array = array_as_string.split.map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: Thanks! Learnt a new sugary shortcut :)